# What should I use to compare DBNull ? Using DBNull.Value or ToString().IsNullOrEmpty()

Tags: .net, null, dataset, dbnull

I can check for a `DBnull` on a data row using any of the methods.

Either by using

```
if(dr[0][0]==DBNull.Value)
//do somethin
```

or by doing

```
if(dr[0][0].ToString().IsNullOrEmpty())
//do something
```

In Both Cases I will be getting same result.

But Which one is conecptually right approach. Which was will use less resources

Comment: `.ToString().IsNullOrEmpty()`? Does a data **row** have 2 indices, `dr[0][0]`? And what if `dr[0][0]` is null, you can't call `.ToString()`. It is usually best to provide working code to get better answers.

Comment: @Kobi: My mistake you are right I meant to say DataTable if taking two indexers

Comment: for the second case, if the value in that column is null you'll be getting an error

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The first way is somewhat correct.
However, more accepted way is:

```
if ( dr[0][0] is DBNull )
```

And the second way is definitely incorrect. If you use the second way, you will get true in two cases:

1. Your value is DBNull
2. Your value is an empty string

Answer (score 10):

Conceptually the comparison to `DBNull.Value` is the correct one.

You can also use :

```
if (Convert.IsDBNull(dr[0]))
{
}
```

You could also use, which I'm not a fan of, purely because it's a type comparison rather than a value comparison:

```
if (dr[0] is DBNull)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is always use :

```
dr[0].IsNull(0)
```

Assuming that the creators of this function know the best way/most efficient way of comparing..

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way

```
if (dr[0][0] == DBNull.Value)
//do somethin
```

is perfectly valid and readable.

Even though `==` compares references, it works here because [`DBNUll.Value` is the only instance of `DBNull` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx) - so all `DBNull` values are actually this exact reference.