# How to compare decimal DBNull in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

```
someDS.someDT.Where(x => x.Amount is not DBNull)
             .Sum(x => x.Amount);
```

According to the link [How to compare DBNull value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393958/what-should-i-use-to-compare-dbnull-using-dbnull-value-or-tostring-isnullore), the above code should be fine or is there any other way to handle the above scenario?

Comment: What is type of `x.Amount`. If it is `DataRow` then use `x.Amount != DBNull.Value`

Answer (score 0):

If your `Amount` is a nullable `decimal` then you can check `null` value of nullable `decimal` type as

```
someDS.someDT.Where(x => x.Amount.HasValue == true)
             .Sum(x => x.Amount);
```

Comment: `System.DBNull` does not contain a definition for 'value'

Comment: check updated one

Comment: @Mr.SuicideSheep try updated answer

Comment: why down vote, please explain it will help to improve answer

Comment: It wasn't me, but seems like OP have pointed in comments to you, that your answer not working

Comment: yeah it was previous answer comment after that I have updated answer, and down vote come after that, I think someone have got something they can suggest me to improve

Answer (score 0):

```
  someDS.someDT.Where(x => x.Amount != DBNull.Value)
         .Sum(x => x.Amount);
```

Comment: Operator '!='  cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'System.DBNull'

Comment: strange I have posted same answer and op said not working but who upvoted ?